# Change string (text-element) in svg-element

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm just playing around with some svg-drawings.
Actually I have a svg-drawing, that contains some grouped Elements.
I like to copy one of These Elements and give it e new value in its Text-field.

First I copy the Element:

```
var selectedSymbol = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
if(selectedSymbol.length >>0)
{
    var newSymbol = selectedSymbol[0].cloneNode(true);
    //now Change Information of <text id='BMK'>emptyBMK</text>
}
```

Of course every grouped Symbol has this text-field, with same id, so I think I Need to Change it only in selected Symbol but newSymbol.getElementsById('BMK') does not work :(

Comment: `newSymbol.id = "newUniqueID"`

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean.
The grouped Elements have their unique Id but the id of the text is the same in every grouped element.
So I Need to Change the text-node inside the cloned node, before I append it to the svg-drwaing

Comment: this is an example of a very simple grouped Element.:  

    <g class='draggable preview' pointer-events='fill' transform='translate(0,0)' id='225' ><circle cx='21' cy='21' r='20' fill='none'></circle><polyline points='1 21 21 1 41 21' fill='none' /><text id='BMK' text-anchor='end' x='-2' y='25' fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" font-size="16px" font-family="Sans-serif">#{BMK}</text></g>

Comment: Ah, it's a descendant? Then you can do `newSymbol.querySelector('[id=BMK]')` to get it. `getElementById` can only be used on the document as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it, but I am not sure if this is a good practice:

```
for (var x = 0; x < newSymbol.childElementCount; x++)
{
    if(newSymbol.Children[x].id == "BMK")
        newSymbol.children[x].innerHTML = "newBMK";
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is ok?
I mean it works but seems a bit strange to me.